# Running two while loops simultaneously, while sharing state. Asyncio or Queue?

Tags: python, asynchronous, curses

I'm trying to get Python's `curses` and `python-slackclient` to work together, but both of them utilize a while loop. I'm new to asynchronous programming and so am having trouble figuring out the best solution to the problem.

I need both of these while loops to run simultaneously, and be able to share information with each other. When `slackclient` receives data, it needs to be displayed on the screen. When a user enters text, it needs to be sent out over `slackclient`.

I've been able to write a test run of `slackclient` that uses `asyncio` to listen on stdin, and write out what it hears from stdin. However I'm stuck here and don't know how to proceed. What might my next step be?

Here's the `slackclient`/`asyncio` test code:

```
import asyncio
import time
import sys
from slackclient import SlackClient

class SlackCLI(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.token = 'xoxp-TOKEN-HIDDEN'
        self.client = SlackClient(self.token)
        self.channel = '#general'

    def callback(self):
        text = sys.stdin.readline()

        print('[*] sending: {} to channel {}'.format(text, self.channel))
        print(self.client.api_call('chat.postMessage', channel='#general',
                                   text='{}'.format(text),
                                   username='pybot123', icon_emoji=':robot_face:'))

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def run(self):
        if self.client.rtm_connect():
            while True:
                last = self.client.rtm_read()
                if last:
                    try:
                        text = last[0]['text']
                        chan = last[0]['channel']
                        print('[!] {}: {}'.format(chan, text))

                    except:
                        pass

                yield from asyncio.sleep(1)
        else:
            print('connection failed')

    def main(self):
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.add_reader(sys.stdin, self.callback)
        loop.run_until_complete(self.run())


a = SlackCLI()
a.main()
```